# "git ftp init" without sending all the files

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

We're using BitBucket Pipelines for the first time and we have a fully developed and deployed Joomla site.

When I try to set up pipelines to push all the new maintenance changes it fails because I need to use "git ftp init" to begin with.

But this means pushing ALL the code from repo to the server even though I already have it on the server... and it also means using up ALL of my available pipeline time because pushing a full Joomla website takes 3 or 4 hours.

Is there any way to "init" the FTP without sending all the files, or simple skipping the 'init' stage and go straight to the 'push' stage?

Here is my YMAL file:

```
    image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp push --user $USERNAME --passwd $PASSWORD ftp://********/public_html/
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here:

[Avoid git-ftp upload if files already on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205032/avoid-git-ftp-upload-if-files-already-on-server)

You can use the 'git ftp catchup' function to skip the init.